# Change cod-file programmatically

Tags: blackberry, hex

Is this possible to change programmatically a cod file installed in BlackBerry?

Like this:

My cod file have 1KB(Example)

```
84746474=RIM Runtime API..84747464=RIM Blackberry Apps API.
```

In HEX:

```
37 34 38 34 38 34 38 34 52 49 4D 20 52 75 6E 74 69 6D 65 20 41 50 49 0D 0A 37 34 38 34 38 34 38 34 3D 52 49 4D 20 42 6C 61 63 6B 62 65 72 72 79 20 41 70 70 73 20 41 50 49 0D 0A
```

I want to replace offset from: 27 to 31. (BlackBerry)

TXT: BlackBerry in HEX = 42 6C 61 63 6B 62 65 72 72 79 20

I want to replace like this: Developers = 44 65 76 65 6C 6F 70 65 72 73

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

COD-files, installed on actual device are signed.

If you change anything inside of COD-file, then the signature will become broken and this COD-file will become unusable.

Comment: And another file? Edit from offsite to destination offsite.